# Why using utp cable for ADSL modem

Tags: connection, modem, adsl

I met a site with ADSL modem.There using utp cat6 cable for connecting DSLAM to ADSL modem.But we know, for ADSL modem,required only 1 pair.Now I am asking why used utp cable on there. All other 3 pairs are wasting.
   Anyone have answer, please clear my doubt..

Answer (score 0):

Because you often can't easily get high quality single pair cabling. Even when telecomms staff run drop wires into homes they use 2 pair (4 wire) cables, you only see "bell wire" within a home or small business.

CAT5 would do just fine, but as the price difference is so small nowadays many electricians and telecomms staffers will just use CAT6 everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for usefull information.any speed profit with utp compared to 2 pair wire